# Laravel Passport - use custom user provider to authenticate with external API while leveraging Passport's request authorization

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I've been tasked to write an API which serves as a proxy to another external API (because this API can't be accessed directly though the browser due to CORS) but with its own request authorization and user authentication layer.

I'm looking into Laravel Passport as a potential solution to this but I'm having a hard time understanding how authorization and authentication can be abstracted into custom logic.

So, what I'd like to do is use the Password Client and send the username and password along with the client ID and secret, I want to use an external API to check that the username and password are OK, but want to leverage Passport in issuing and authenticating tokens. So based on the result of the external API call, the tokens are issued/denied

I can't call the external API directly from the browser because of CORS, so the app is essentially a proxy for another API. Essentially, I can't use the users table to check the details supplied.

I'd like to use custom user provider to take the username/password and authenticate the user with the external API before issuing tokens with Passport, then be able to send said token to protected routes with `auth:api` middleware. Is this possible?

Below is what I've managed so far... Any advice on this would be appreciated.

---

In `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Auth::provider('bc', function ($app) {
        return new BigcommerceUserProvider($app['bc']);
    });
}
```

In `config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'external',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'external' => [
        'driver' => 'bc',
    ],
],
```

In `app/Auth/Bigcommerce/UserProvider.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth\Bigcommerce;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as UserContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use App\Services\Bigcommerce\Bigcommerce;
use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;

class UserProvider implements UserContract
{
    /**
     * Bigcommerce service instance
     *
     * @var \App\Services\Bigcommerce\Bigcommerce
     */
    public $bigcommerce;

    /**
     * The provider instance.
     *
     * @param \App\Services\Bigcommerce\Bigcommerce $bigcommerce
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Bigcommerce $bigcommerce)
    {
        $this->bigcommerce = $bigcommerce;
    }

     /**
     * Retrieve a user by their unique identifier.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $identifier
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        // @note Not implemented yet...
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->bigcommerce
                ->setVersion('v3')
                ->getCustomers([
                    'email:in' => $credentials['username'],
                ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }

        if (count($customer) === 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->getGenericUser($customer[0]);
    }

    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        try {
            $validPassword = $this->bigcommerce
                ->setVersion('v2')
                ->validateCustomerPassword($user->getAuthIdentifier(), $credentials['password']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }

        return $validPassword['success'] ?? false;
    }

    /**
     * Gets an instance of an generic user.
     *
     * @param mixed $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser|null
     */
    public function getGenericUser($user)
    {
        return !is_null($user) ? new GenericUser($user) : null;
    }

    /**
     * Empty methods implemented to satisfy contract
     */
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token) {}
    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token) {}
}
```

Comment: Is anyone able to advise on this?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? i'm having the same issue

Comment: I'm also facing the same situation.